# Children's/YA fantasy book where the protagonist is briefly possessed by the villain

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book/series that I read probably 8-10 years ago (although it could have come out earlier). In the book, the hero makes some kind of deal with a possessing entity, where that entity gets control of their body for a couple minutes, but the deal involves the entity not doing anything bad (like hurting or killing their friends, etc.). At a climactic moment, the entity takes control of the hero to *stop* them doing something important/stopping something bad from happening.

Other things: I'm pretty sure it was a high-fantasy children's book, in the vein of *Fablehaven*.

**Edit:** Some other details I can dredge up: the hero in question is a male child, and I think it's a book where the fantasy world is separated by a portal/gate from Earth.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @CBonkov - Can you be a bit more specific about what kind of person the hero is? Are they male or female? A child, teenager, or adult? Do they go to school, or are they employed? Can you describe any other significant characters in the story, such as relatives or friends?